# Shorten list of version numbers in Mantis

Tags: mantis

I have a Mantis bug tracker installed that we use for all of our products. One product goes through a rapid development cycle and each new build gets a new version number (the build number is incremented). Since our QA has to report all bugs they found for the build that introduced the bug, we also have to add a new version number to Mantis every time a new build is made. Because of this, the list of version numbers under `Manage`->`Manage Projects`->*`Project name`* is now very long.

I just tried to delete one of the very old version numbers but that removes that number from all issues that referred to it. (Makes sense from a DB design point-of-view.)

Is there a way to shorten the version list without affecting the issues? The very old version number we have will never be used again but I want the old issues intact. I did a bunch of Google searches but I keep getting flooded with unrelated results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you properly, what you'd like is a way to filter the versions displayed in the Manage Projects page.

This cannot be done in current version of MantisBT (1.2.14), and would require a change in the code. I suggest you open a feature request on our [tracker](http://mantisbt.org/bugs). If you end up implementing the feature, then submit it as a pull request on our [Github repository](https://github.com/mantisbt/mantisbt).

Comment: Thanks - I suspected this but it's good to have confirmation. It's not likely I'd implement this myself since I'm usually very busy with work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the *obsolete* attribute of version ?
As said in the [admin guide](http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide/admin.project.html) :

> Each project can have several versions, which are marked with attributes like released and obsolete.

and :

> Once a version is marked as obsolete, it is now longer included in the change log.

See also these issues :

1. [Obsolete versions not selectable as filter in `View Issues'](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=12636)
2. [Versions marked as obsolete appear on change log page](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=11604)

Comment: Yes, I did - in fact, it's used very frequently. It's useful to hide version numbers from the version dropdowns but in the admin screens, all version numbers still show up. I'm looking for a way to shorten that list. Unfortunately, if I delete one, all issues using that particular version number will now show a blank field for version.